# How to import open document spreadsheet into database using YII

Tags: yii, phpexcel

I storing my user details in open document spreadsheet i want to upload user details to database in same format but it is not working. But in CSV format it is working fine. So my requirement is want to upload open document spreadsheet details to data base i tried but it is not working. I am using yii-1.1

my Excelimport code is:-

```
$filelist=CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('name');   
        foreach($filelist as $file)
            {
                try{        
                $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
                ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
                $handle = fopen("$file->tempName", "r");
                $row = 1;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    if($row>1){
                                date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
                                $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                $SchoolId=Yii::app()->session['Schoolid'];
                                $newmodel=new Puserprofile;      
                                $newmodel->username=$data[0];
                                $newmodel->password=$data[1];
                                $newmodel->repeat_password=$data[2];
                                $newmodel->studentname=$data[3];
                                //$newmodel->classid=$data[4];
                                $classname = $data[4];                                  
                                $newmodel->parentname=$data[5];
                                $newmodel->Phone=$data[6];
                                $newmodel->email=$data[7];                                   
                                $newmodel->save();           
                    }
                    $row++;   
                }

                $transaction->commit();
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
                }catch(Exception $error){
                   print_r($error);        
                    $transaction->rollback();
                }                   
            }
```

Comment: So how did you try to upload and parse an open document spreadsheet? Show your code for that. In what way isn't it working? Does it fail to read the file? Does it give any errors? Does it create incorrect data in your database?

Answer (score 0):

**example file**

odf-file: cells a1,a2,b1,b2 filled with text.

**Step 1: unpack ODF-File**

the odf-formar is nothing more than a container.
So, you can unpack the container with the PHP build-in Class "ZipArchive"
I recommend to create a temp-folder in protected/runtime, in this tut i call the 
folder "odfImport".

```
$objZip = new ZipArchive;
$result = $objZip->open($objFile->getTempName());
if ($result === TRUE) {
    $workingDir = sha1(rand().microtime());

    // create temporary Folder in runtime
    if(!is_dir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/protected/runtime/odfImport/'.$workingDir)) 
        CFileHelper::createDirectory(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/protected/runtime/odfImport/'.$workingDir,null,true);

    // Extract Files from odf-container
        $objZip->extractTo(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/protected/runtime/odfImport/".$workingDir);
        $objZip->close();

}
```

on this point, we should have a Folder ./protected/runtime// witch contains 
a lot of xml-files. In this tut, our focus is set on "content.xml". This file contains 
the our content.

**Step 2: parse content.xml**

for this job, you can use "SimpleXMLElement" and the helper "simplexml_load_file".
Please refer to documentation for further informations.
Also you need to configure the prefixes and namespaces of the XML-Document.
For assistance, you can open the content.xml with Firefox or a texteditor.
So, here we go:

```
// load content.xml
$xml = simplexml_load_file(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/protected/runtime/odfImport/".$workingDir."/content.xml",'SimpleXMLElement');
// register some prefixes and namespaces
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('table','table-cell');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('text','p');
// output them
foreach($xml->xpath('//table:table-cell') as $header)
{
    // model crud operation goes here
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($header->xpath('//text:p')); echo "</pre>";
}
```

**Step 3: tidy up**

For development, comment this in.

```
// tidyup
CFileHelper::removeDirectory(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/runtime/odfImport/'.$workingDir);
```

**complete code**

```
$arrUpload = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('files_name');
if($arrUpload) {
    foreach($arrUpload AS $objFile) {
        $objZip = new ZipArchive;
            $result = $objZip->open($objFile->getTempName());
            if ($result === TRUE) {

                $workingDir = sha1(rand().microtime());

                // create temporary Folder in runtime
                if(!is_dir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/protected/runtime/odfImport/'.$workingDir)) 
                    CFileHelper::createDirectory(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/protected/runtime/odfImport/'.$workingDir,null,true);

                // Extract Files from odf-container
                $objZip->extractTo(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/protected/runtime/odfImport/".$workingDir);
                $objZip->close();

                // load content.xml
                $xml = simplexml_load_file(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/protected/runtime/odfImport/".$workingDir."/content.xml",'SimpleXMLElement');
                // register some prefixes and namespaces
                $xml->registerXPathNamespace('table','table-cell');
                $xml->registerXPathNamespace('text','p');
                // output them
                foreach($xml->xpath('//table:table-cell') as $header)
                {
                    // model crud operation goes here
                    echo "<pre>"; print_r($header->xpath('//text:p')); echo "</pre>";
                }

                // tidyup
                CFileHelper::removeDirectory(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/runtime/odfImport/'.$workingDir);
            }
    } 
}
```